# How to list contact us records in Magento admin?

Tags: php, xml, magento

I'm new to magento.
I'm successfully added records of contacts page into the database.Now I can't listing it admin.I'm using magento 1.9.2.0
my admin html xml is app\code\local\Avijit\Contacts\etc\adminhtml.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<menu>
    <mycustomtab>
        <title>Contacts</title>
        <sort_order>71</sort_order>
        <children>
            <index>
                <title>Contact us</title>
                <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                <action>adminhtml/contacts/</action>
            </index>               
        </children>
    </mycustomtab>
</menu>
<acl>
    <resources>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <contacts>
                    <title>My Controller</title>
                    <sort_order>200</sort_order>
                    <children>
                        <index>
                            <title>Index Action</title>
                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                        </index>                           
                    </children>
                </contacts>
            </children>
        </admin>
    </resources>
</acl>
</config>
```

app\code\local\Avijit\Contacts\controllers\Adminhtml\ContactsController.php

```
class Avijit_Contacts_Adminhtml_ContactsController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{

    public function indexAction()
    {

            $this->loadLayout()->_setActiveMenu('contacts/items');
            $this->renderLayout();

    }   

}
```

app\design\adminhtml\default\default\layout\contacts.xml

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <contacts_adminhtml_contacts_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="domain" template="contacts/contacts.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </contacts_adminhtml_contacts_index>
</layout>
```

app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\contacts\contacts.phtml

It shows 404 page. My question is how do I show contact records(from database)?

Comment: You're using 1.9.2.0 I think it's nowadays required to check the ACL'ing your own on the controller class, too. However just telling you get a 404 does not really turn this into a programming question IMHO. Also your question does not contain any material about showing contact records. You just have the 404 issue. In it's current forms sounds like a 1.) support request and then 2.) a coding request. That's not good form for a Q&A site like Stackoverflow.